# grouping multiple variables - R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to group a data frame of different topics and different users to generate a table of relative importance of each user in that topic, e.g my data frame is

```
Topic User
A     U1
A     U2
B     U2
A     U1
B     U1
A     U1
```

And I want to reduce it to

```
Topic  User Importance
 A     U1    0.75
 A     U2    0.25
 B     U1    0.5
 B     U2    0.5
```

Can anybody point me how to do it using R preferably dplyr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick `data.table` alternative approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, as.data.table(table(User)/.N), by = Topic]
#    Topic User    N
# 1:     A   U1 0.75
# 2:     A   U2 0.25
# 3:     B   U1 0.50
# 4:     B   U2 0.50
```

---

This is basically just runs `table(User)` by group and divides it by groups size `.N`

---

Or simiarly with `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  group_by(Topic) %>%
  do(data.frame(table(.$User)/length(.$User)))

# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: Topic [2]
# 
#    Topic   Var1  Freq
#   (fctr) (fctr) (dbl)
# 1      A     U1  0.75
# 2      A     U2  0.25
# 3      B     U1  0.50
# 4      B     U2  0.50
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to handle this is to count by topic / topic-user separately and join results:

```
topic_count <- df %>% group_by(Topic) %>% summarise(total=n())
user_count <- df %>% group_by(Topic, User) %>% summarise(cnt=n())

user_count %>%
    left_join(topic_count, by="Topic") %>%
    mutate(Importance=cnt/total) %>%
    select(-cnt, -total) # Drop obsolete columns

##   Topic User Importance
## 1 A       U1       0.75
## 2 A       U2       0.25
## 3 B       U1       0.50
## 4 B       U2       0.50
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```
as.data.frame(prop.table(table(DF), margin = 1))
#  Topic User Freq
#1     A   U1 0.75
#2     B   U1 0.50
#3     A   U2 0.25
#4     B   U2 0.50
```

Comment: Yes, that was already posted and deleted by @RichardScrinven for some reason

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry, wasn't aware; shall Richard undelete, I'll delete mine

Comment: Yeah I know, you don't have sufficient rep to see this (even after your awesome answer on my question ;)). I've asked him to undelete but he didn't respond.